# How to remove routes added by other vendormodules in SilverStripe 4?

Tags: url-routing, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have installed the Blog module for SilverStripe 4, but do not want all the different routes that it has available.

I want to remove for instance the "profile", "archive" and "tag" routes. Those routes are defined by the module's BlogController class.

How can I ensure these are replaced with a HTTP 404 response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `your_module_folder/_config/config.yml`_if you indicate it should be processed `After` the `blog` module and you define those routes it should overwrite them:

```
---
name: your_module
After:
  - 'blog/*'
---
SilverStripe\Control\Director:
  rules:
    'profile/': 'MyCustomController'
    'archive/': 'MyCustomController'
    'tag/': 'MyCustomController'
```

Please review the [routing documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/controllers/routing/)

The controller should only have one action that throws a 404 http error.

```
use SilverStripe\Control\Director;
use SilverStripe\View\Requirements;

class MyCustomController extends Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = ['index'];

    public function index(HTTPRequest $request) {
        return $this->httpError(404, "Not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I want them to be a 404, I guess I would have to do that in my controller? Or is there a better or more direct way to achive that?

Comment: @FedericoJM yes, if in your controller you use "return $this->httpError(404);" within that controller to return a 404

Comment: thanks. Can you update the answer with that extra info to mark it as the solution?

Comment: @FedericoJM I have updated the answer (and your question) with that extra info